# Getting error on inserting image into database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting an error on inserting image into database.
Given below is the code which I'm trying to inserting an image but couldn't be able to do it correctly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class welcome : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string fname;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    string emailname;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Session["Username"] == null) && (Session["useraddress"] == null))
        {
            Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            emailname = Session["useremail"].ToString();
            Label2.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
            Label3.Text = Session["useraddress"].ToString();
            welcomelbl.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
            addlbl.Text = Session["useraddress"].ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imageupload();
    }
```

The function which I'm using to upload image is given below.

```
    private void imageupload()
    {
            int imglength = FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            byte[] bytearray = new byte[imglength];
            fname = FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName;
            TextBox1.Text = fname;
            HttpPostedFile image = FileUpload2.PostedFile;
            image.InputStream.Read(bytearray, 0, imglength);
            SqlConnection con = Connection.conn();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into imgtbl (imgname,img,useraddress) values(@name ,@image '" + emailname + "')", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bytearray;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: please format your question, specify the error message and where exactly in the code you encounter the error

Comment: why arent u adding `useraddress` with same method as `imgname` and `img`

Comment: 'My code have the error' is not a sufficiently detailed bug report.

Comment: my error is that "syntax error near xyz@gmail.com".hear xyz@gmail.com is a +emailname+ that we want to insert in imgtb Table

Comment: @user3230665 And that *syntax* error didn't lead you to checking your SQL syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The following is wrong (you're missing a comma between `@image` and the string that contains `emailname`):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into imgtbl (imgname,img,useraddress) values(@name ,@image '" + emailname + "')", con);
```

It should be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into imgtbl (imgname,img,useraddress) values(@name ,@image, '" + emailname + "')", con); // Note the missing comma!
```

Also you started correctly by parameterizing your query, why not the email address? This is user input and thus parameterizing is really a *must do* to avoid SQL injection.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into imgtbl (imgname,img,useraddress) values(@name ,@image, @emailname)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bytearray;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailname;
```

---

Another thing: Do you want international users to use your site? Then you should really switch from `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR` to allow for unicode characters in names.

Comment: tank you  for helping me

Comment: i want to upload an image with session user so hear we are using emailname as a session value

Comment: @user3230665 I actually have no idea what your second comment means, but I still feel you should use `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` and parameterized queries instead of string concatenation. Just in case you tried to defend both design decisions :-) Just because you always, *always* should use parameterized queries. No exceptions, no excuses.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: +1 for your NVARCHAR observation

Answer (score 0):

When passing data to your SQL server, you should always try to use parameters instead of manually building SQL commands with concatenation.

Instead of:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into imgtbl (imgname,img,useraddress) values(@name ,@image '" + emailname + "')", con);
```

you should parametrize the email name also, like you did with `@name` and `@image`:

```
string sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO imgtbl (imgname, img, useraddress) VALUES (@name, @image, @emailName)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", bytearray);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailname", emailname);
```

This will prevent any malformed sql commands to be sent to the database, but most importantly, it will make your calls much more safer. Otherwise you will be exposed to SQL injection attacks!

UPDATE: check out @ThorstenDittmar response, the missing comma is probably causing the syntax error

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - just noticed that in the OP question; you have good eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

Please correct you `query`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into imgtbl (imgname,img,useraddress) values(@name ,@image '" + emailname + "')", con);
```

it should be like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO imgtbl (imgname, img, useraddress) VALUES (@name, @image, '" + emailname + "')", con);
```

You missed `comma` in your query.